# How to pass the value that you type on textbox to a controller every time you type without having to have a submit button.

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the fallowing code that is working but my question is how do you get to pass the value of the textbox every time you type on the textbox? Maybe Using Javascript or JQuery ? If anyone could help me it would be great.

SearchProducstController:

```
public class SearchProducstController: Controller
{
 public ActionResult searchmain(string name)
    {
        var result = name; 
        return View();
    }
```

site.master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1- strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="page">     

        <% using (Html.BeginForm("searchmain", "SearchProducstController")) { %>
        <%: Html.TextBox("name") %>
        <input type="submit" value="searchmain" />

        <% } %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried handling the on leave event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AJAX(Asynchronous JavaScript and XML).
AJAX is the art of exchanging data with a server, and updating parts of a web page - without reloading the whole page.
AJAX was invented for this feature only.
Google **ajax autocomplete textbox** and you will find what i am talking about.